# R Neural Net Package querying

Tags: r, neural-network

I've been following through the Neuralnet library in R from the book 'Machine Learning with R - Second Edition: Expert techniques for predictive modeling to solve all your data analysis problems'.  The model is created as below

```
concrete_model2 <- neuralnet(strength ~ cement + slag +
                           ash + water + superplastic +
                           coarseagg + fineagg + age,
                           data = concrete_train, hidden = 5)
```

It all works as it should and can be fine tuned etc.  What the book doesn't show is once the network is trained and confirmed, how do you get it to predict the strength field given the other inputs from a query?  i.e. How do I get the network to predict the strength value from the other fields cement,slag,ash,water,superplastic,courseagg,fineagg,age ?

I'd be most glad for some pointers.

Comment: `compute(concrete_model2, covariate=newData)`

Comment: Aha, I see thanks.  The data returned is of course normalised as per the other variables.  How would I 'un-normalise' the answers?  The function to normailse was from the book as normalize <- function(x) {
    return((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
  }     Or once it is trained can I use just normal values?

Comment: If you want the outputs to be in-normalized,  you need to use the parameter `linear.output=TRUE` in your original `neuralnet` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!